# The trait bound `Complex<f64>: approx::abs_diff_eq::AbsDiffEq<_>` is not satisfied

Tags: rust

I'm trying to compare two `ndarray::Array1<Complex64>` using the `approx` crate. I can compare two `f64` arrays no problem:

```rust
#[test]
fn repro() {
    let a = ndarray::array![1.0, 0.0];
    let b = ndarray::array![1.0, 0.0];

    assert!(a.abs_diff_eq(&b, 0.1));
}
```

but for the life of me can't compare two complex arrays:

```rust
#[test]
fn repro() {
    let a = ndarray::array![
        Complex64::new(1.0, 0.0)
    ];
    let b = ndarray::array![
        Complex64::new(1.0, 0.0)
    ];

    assert!(a.abs_diff_eq(&b, 0.1));
}
```

with the error message

```
  --> src/lib.rs:85:31
   |
85 |         assert!(a.abs_diff_eq(&b, 0.1));
   |                   ----------- ^^^^^^ the trait `approx::abs_diff_eq::AbsDiffEq<_>` is not implemented for `Complex<f64>`
   |                   |
   |                   required by a bound introduced by this call
```

But I know that this trait [is in fact implemented for `Complex<T>`](https://docs.rs/approx/latest/src/approx/abs_diff_eq.rs.html#169-185), and the feature `num-complex` is enabled.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guess you're using feature `"approx"` for `ndarray`. You want `"approx-0_5"`.

```ini
[dependencies]
approx = { version = "0.5.*", features = ["num-complex"] }
ndarray = { version = "0.15.*", features = ["approx-0_5"] }
num-complex = { version = "0.4.*" }
```

Comment: Yes, that fixes it! Can you explain what that feature does differently?

Comment: It switches the version of `approx` that `ndarray` uses from 0.4 to 0.5, but I don't understand why exactly that fixes things. One would probably have to delve into the `approx` source code to figure out why.